# Need some suggestions on what algorithm to use

Tags: algorithm

Its a simple game in c++ .

There are 5 random towers generated in coordinate range (0.0f,0.0f) to (10.0f,10.0f).
They have  random hp,range and damage capped within a certain limit. They can't move.

Now , 10 units are added on the map with fixed movement speed, hp and damage.

No of units and towers will be fixed through simulations . Only their initial position will be randomized.
1000 simulations are to be run.

Goal is to achieve a win rate of 90% approx for units.

A game is won when units destroy all of the towers . Units can move at a predefined speed towards tower. Each simulation takes multiple rounds to complete. In each round unit move towards best selected target and attack if within a certain range. Similarly towers pick any one unit within its attack range and keeps attacking it until it dies or moves out of range.

I need some pointers on what algorithms shall i invest my time in to achieve the same.

Currently , I am able to achieve 84.2% win rate using some weighted average of distance from unit, hp ,range and damage of towers and selecting the tower which scores least on these criteria. Moving towards tower with least distance from unit without considering other attributes achieves a win rate of approx 72 % .

---

**From comment of deleted answer:**

There is one more restriction . I can just select a target each time. The units will make sure to move towards that target . I am not supposed to modify the part where units move towards target . So , there has to be a target tower each round of a simulation towards which unit targeting it will move. So , there is no way i can move my units away from tower to a safe area and assemble them at a point and then plan my attack.

Comment: `Goal is to achieve a win rate of...`. **How** do you win?

Comment: When units destroy all of the towers . Units can move at a predefined speed towards tower. Each simulation takes multiple rounds to complete. In each round unit move towards best selected target and attack if within a certain range. Similarly towers pick any one unit within its attack range and keeps attacking it until it dies or moves out of range.

Comment: way too vague. If I tell you that to win chess you need to capture the king, you will not be able to provide any algorithm. You need to explain how the game is **played**

Comment: If you are already achieving 84.2% win rate, I think you should just adjust the formula used to select the next target. Try making HP more important then damage and so on, I know it's not an optimal solution but after all you are trying to achieve some sort of Artificial Intelligence and you can only do that by trial and error. I suggest making a method that will generate random parameters for the formula, within a range, until you find the best one

Comment: @MarkusJarderot If units can switch targets at any point, it should be possible to have them stay reasonably at the same place by switching between towers + move away from towers by picking a tower in the opposite direction (assuming there exists towers to allow this).

Comment: I'm assuming the game uses an event-based simulator, with no interaction once it's started. This is to let the simulation go as quickly as possible, so that many can be run in sequence. I wrote something similar. But without similar number generation, the balance is off. http://ideone.com/wlaPSa

Answer (score 1):

I've had a better idea for a formula to select what tower to attack.

For each of the warriors use it to get a "score" for each tower. Then select the tower with the highest score

```
a1*todalDmgFromOtherWarriorsAimedAtThatTower - a2*towerRange - a3*towerDamage - a4*towerHP - a5*distance/speed
```

a1-a5 should be modified again and again until you get the optimal result making some parameters more important than others

Comment: Another parameter might be towerHP*towerDamage, since that is proportional to total damage the tower can inflict before dying.

Comment: or maybe add towerDamage/towerHP because you would want to kill off a tower with lower HP and higher damage rather than leaving it alive

Comment: I am using similar approach as well. i think i will try to tweak it even further  using few more parameters as you have pointed out.. will let ya know if it improves win rate ..cheers !!!

Comment: @cosmin.danisor How much damage it does won't really matter while all your units are outside of range of the tower. It may be more efficient to take out the weaker towers first (already included with `-a3*towerDamage` or, as Markus suggested - `(-)Damage*HP`), since, even with low HP, a high damage tower could take out a few of your units before they can get to it, leaving you much weaker to take out the rest of the towers.

Answer (score 1):

**If there is no time limit or advantage for time**, I would try to go for a **grouped approach** - let all units attack the same tower together, and have all units enter the tower's attack range at the exact same time. This may actually end up not taking that much longer, since you'll fire faster while taking less damage and thus not have to account for preventing units from dying as much, also producing a much higher (if not perfect) win rate.

You can possibly have a specific unit (one with the highest HP?) enter the range slightly before the other units so it draws fire and can move out of range when it's close to death. If the strongest unit has moved out of range, you can either move the next attacked unit out of range too (and so on) or simply continue attacking until the tower is destroyed.

You'll have to play around with which tower to attack first. Probably the weakest (lowest HP + damage), but you may not want to send in your strongest unit to draw fire, because you probably want to keep this for the last, strongest tower.

Moving a unit such to avoid the attack range of all the towers to get to the desired tower may be difficult. Some options:

- Leave the unit where it is.
- Pick towers strategically to 'untrap' the strongest units.
- Attack multiple towers.

**If all of this sounds like a near-impossible task**, requiring some really advanced AI, note that it may be a lot simpler than you think. Just ignore most of the constraints to start and add them in one at a time, as in start simple and build it up from there. But yes, it's a lot more difficult than your individual approach; the main difficulty lies in the geometry calculations and playing around a bit to find the best order of attack for the towers and order of damage-takers.

**How I would probably approach this:** (test the efficiency at every step and stop when you're happy)

- Write a heuristic to determine the best tower. Move all your units there to attack it (ignoring all other towers). Repeat until the game ends. This should be really simple.
- Modify to wait until most units are there before entering the tower range. Shouldn't be too difficult.
- **You can stop here if you want**, before any difficult stuff starts happening (maybe hack at it a little to improve), thus it shouldn't have taken you too long, and simply compare this to your current approach.
- Write some simple code to have units move around other towers (if possible).
- Modify your picking-tower code to redetermine a tower if some units can't get there.
- Incrementally make everything more complicated.

Side note - Since the towers are static, you can determine the time it will take to get to a tower ahead of time, so you can just wait at a safe spot (rather than just outside range of the tower, which may be inside range of multiple other towers) if other units will take longer to get there.

Additional note - If units can be ranged too, if any unit has a longer attack range than any tower, it would be most efficient to have that unit solo that tower until it is destroyed (FREE KILL!).